# SUM inside SUM SQL Invalid use of group function

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, left-join, aggregate-functions

Hi I want to perform a calculation inside a SUM with my sql, but there is one SUM field that consist of other SUM fields. I get the General error: 1111 Invalid use of group function. What is the proper way of summing other sum fields in SQL?

I can't use the alias of other sum fields to perform the calculation because it says that the alias is unidentified.

This part is my problem

```
SUM((SUM(transactions.payable) + SUM(transactions.discount) ) - SUM(deliveries.delivery_fee) ) AS raw_sales
```

Thank you

Here is my SQL.

```
     SELECT
        MONTHNAME(transactions.date_transac) AS MONTH,
        SUM(transactions.payable) AS total,
        SUM(transactions.discount) AS discount,
        SUM(deliveries.delivery_fee) AS delivery,
        SUM(
            (
                SUM(transactions.payable) + SUM(transactions.discount)
            ) - SUM(deliveries.delivery_fee)
        ) AS raw_sales,
        MONTH(transactions.date_transac) AS monthnum
    FROM
        `transactions`
    LEFT JOIN `requisitions` ON `transactions`.`requisition_id` = `requisitions`.`id`
    LEFT JOIN `transactions` AS `ct`
    ON
        `transactions`.`code` = `ct`.`charge_transaction_code`
    LEFT JOIN `deliveries` ON `transactions`.`delivery_id` = `deliveries`.`id`
    WHERE
    `transactions`.`transaction_type` = Sale AND YEAR(`transactions`.`date_transac`) = 2020
GROUP BY
    `month`
ORDER BY
    `monthnum` ASC
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sibe.png)

Comment: Now try to understand the relation between GROUP BY expression and both SUM() expressions... do you understand that GROUP BY cannot be relative to both? PS. External SUM must be removed.

Comment: please read [mre] and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Yeeees! it worked I wasn't thinking about that. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can't nest aggregate functions. Here, I suspect that you could move the arithmetics within the aggregate function rather than attempting to nest:

```
SUM(
    transactions.payable 
    + transactions.discount 
    - COALESCE(deliveries.delivery_fee, 0)
) AS raw_sales
```

`delivery_fee` comes from a `left join` table so it could be `null`, hence we use `coalesce()`.

That said, I am quite suspicious about the logic of your query. I am wondering, for example, why `transactions` appears twice in the `from` clause. There are also missing quotes around literal string "Sale" in the `WHERE` clause. If you were to ask a legitimate question, including sample data, desired results, and an explanation of the purpose of the query, one might be able to suggests optimizations.

Comment: Your recommendation code calculates but it doesn't give the desired data. Assuming that I got a $31,661 accumulated sales in the month of October but it includes the accumulated discount and delivery fees for that month. All I want for raw sales is that it wont include the accumulated discount and delivery fees for that month . 
The purpose of this query is for a chart.

You are also wondering that the query has missing quotes or others, it is because it is the result of an eloquent, I just copied it from the error

Answer (score 0):

The query just worked, I haven't realized that it is no longer necessary to calculate all Sum fields. I just removed the external sum.